# vb6 login to website winhttp with my code here

Tags: vb6

please someone kindly review this code and help me fix it so i can login. i am unable to login.
if i login via firefox and capture the packets and use that login cookie in this winhttp then this code loggs in ok. i just need to know how to get the cookie to work with my code

```
Text1.Text = ""
    Text13.Text = ""
    Dim httpReq As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim strLineOut As String
    Dim strReturn As String
    Dim strStatus As String
    strLineOut = "username=laxom47743@5k2u.com&password=test12312&credentialId="
    ''httpReq.Open "POST", "https://accounts.zerotier.com//auth/realms/zerotier/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=o8twzbdn6KXGaRi27fyZDwH1pwuHfQlcYn-0AhzpPgc&execution=86f116b6-9ab4-4790-acb0-bb7ac9eb98d0&client_id=zt-central&tab_id=zciqEAPtfYI", False
    httpReq.Open "POST", "https://accounts.zerotier.com/auth/realms/zerotier/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=" & Text4.Text & "execution=" & Text6.Text & "&client_id=" & Text9.Text & "&tab_id=" & Text10.Text, False
    
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Host", " accounts.zerotier.com"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", Text12.Text
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept", " text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Language", " en-GB,en;q=0.5"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", " gzip, deflate, br"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", " application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", " 50"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Origin", " null"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Connection", " keep-alive"
    
    'httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", " AUTH_SESSION_ID=" & Text9.Text & ".ztc-keycloak-2; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=" & Text9.Text & ".ztc-keycloak-2; KC_RESTART=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJkNjhjZTJjZS01ZThjLTRhNjMtYjllOS05NzljZGU3YmQwNzkifQ.eyJjaWQiOiJ6dC1jZW50cmFsIiwicHR5Ijoib3BlbmlkLWNvbm5lY3QiLCJydXJpIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9teS56ZXJvdGllci5jb20vYXBpL19hdXRoL29pZGMvY2FsbGJhY2siLCJhY3QiOiJBVVRIRU5USUNBVEUiLCJub3RlcyI6eyJzY29wZSI6Im9wZW5pZCBwcm9maWxlIGVtYWlsIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hY2NvdW50cy56ZXJvdGllci5jb20vYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvemVyb3RpZXIiLCJyZXNwb25zZV90eXBlIjoiY29kZSIsInJlZGlyZWN0X3VyaSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbXkuemVyb3RpZXIuY29tL2FwaS9fYXV0aC9vaWRjL2NhbGxiYWNrIiwic3RhdGUiOiJzdGF0ZSJ9fQ.C4ENxi3c4OxqOlfebggr2H7IJDYrTqLd19Y2WmsanDQ"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", " AUTH_SESSION_ID=2a9ac060-678f-4bba-9b9c-5090f644ba6b.ztc-keycloak-1; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=2a9ac060-678f-4bba-9b9c-5090f644ba6b.ztc-keycloak-1; KC_RESTART=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJkNjhjZTJjZS01ZThjLTRhNjMtYjllOS05NzljZGU3YmQwNzkifQ.eyJjaWQiOiJ6dC1jZW50cmFsIiwicHR5Ijoib3BlbmlkLWNvbm5lY3QiLCJydXJpIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9teS56ZXJvdGllci5jb20vYXBpL19hdXRoL29pZGMvY2FsbGJhY2siLCJhY3QiOiJBVVRIRU5USUNBVEUiLCJub3RlcyI6eyJzY29wZSI6Im9wZW5pZCBwcm9maWxlIGVtYWlsIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hY2NvdW50cy56ZXJvdGllci5jb20vYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvemVyb3RpZXIiLCJyZXNwb25zZV90eXBlIjoiY29kZSIsInJlZGlyZWN0X3VyaSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbXkuemVyb3RpZXIuY29tL2FwaS9fYXV0aC9vaWRjL2NhbGxiYWNrIiwic3RhdGUiOiJzdGF0ZSJ9fQ.C4ENxi3c4OxqOlfebggr2H7IJDYrTqLd19Y2WmsanDQ"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", " 1"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Sec-Fetch-Dest", " document"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Sec-Fetch-Mode", " navigate"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Sec-Fetch-Site", " same-origin"
    httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Sec-Fetch-User", " ?1"
    
    
    Text1.Text = Text1.Text & httpReq.ResponseText
    Text13.Text = Text13.Text & httpReq.GetAllResponseHeaders
    ' signed-in
    If InStr(httpReq.ResponseText, "Your Networks") Then
    Debug.Print "Your Networks"
    
    End If
    Set httpReq = Nothing
```

Comment: anyone ????????????? kindly share some info

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Couple quick thoughts...  #1 `Host`, `Accept-L`, `Accept-E`, and the like... they all shouldn't have a leading space.  #2 You should mask out token values (in your cookie)--tokens are credentials.  Granted, its expired by now, but still...  Beyond that, why don't you get a simple utility that will echo back your request information.  There's several http echo servers and they are invaluable in debugging.